# What is the correct way to load in asymptote a bitmap image with precise scaling?

Tags: asymptote

I am trying to load a bitmap image of a square of 100x100 pixels so that its lower side will reside on the segment (0,0)--(1,0). I am using the command

```
label(graphic("black","width=1cm"),(.5,.5));
```

The result is

[image]

When I change the width to 2cm I get a square slightly smaller than the unit square.

[image]

I went through all the available examples without getting any clue about what I am doing wrong.
Any help is welcome.
And just an additional remark. While the Tikz documentation’s extent is overwhelming, the Asymptote’s documentation has the opposite approach. IMHO this deters people from this superb software.

The code to generate the images is

```
import graph; 

size(7cm,0);
settings.tex="pdflatex";

/* draw grid of horizontal/vertical lines */
void ddrawgrid(real xmin = -5, real xmax =5, real ymin = -5, real ymax = 5, real f=10) { 
    /* grid intervals */
    pen gridpen  = linewidth(0.7) + gray(.7); 
    real dx = 1., dy = 1.; 
    for(real i = ceil(xmin/dx)*dx; i <= floor(xmax/dx)*dx; i += dx)
      draw((i,ymin)--(i,ymax), gridpen);
    for(real i = ceil(ymin/dy)*dy; i <= floor(ymax/dy)*dy; i += dy)
      draw((xmin,i)--(xmax,i), gridpen);

    /* draws axes; NoZero hides '0' label */ 
    Label laxis; laxis.p = fontsize(f); 
    xaxis(xmin, xmax, Ticks(laxis, Step = 1., Size = 2, NoZero),EndArrow(6), above = true); 
    yaxis(ymin, ymax, Ticks(laxis, Step = 1., Size = 2, NoZero),EndArrow(6), above = true); 
}

int m=3,n=2; 

fill(box((0,0), (m,n)), paleyellow); 
ddrawgrid(xmax=m,  xmin=0, ymax=n, ymin=0); 


label(graphic("black","width=1cm"),(.5,.5));
```

The black square is here
[image]

Comment: Could you maybe provide a full code snippet that yields the output of the above picture?

Comment: FYI. In case you don't already know, you can use `//` to mark the rest of a line as a comment.  So you wouldn't need to use both `/*` and `*/` to create single-line comments.

Comment: I know that. This is a code that I copied from somewhere. I just modified it to make the graph invisible. I just wonder if there is a standard or a better way to draw grid lines.

Answer (score 1):

**The main thing to know is that labels are not scaled by the `size` and `unitsize` commands.**  For example, I have modified your code below to show that a 7cm label is the same width as the grid that you drew.

```
import graph; 

size(7cm,0);
settings.tex="pdflatex";

/* draw grid of horizontal/vertical lines */
void ddrawgrid(real xmin = -5, real xmax =5, real ymin = -5, real ymax = 5, real f=10) { 
    /* grid intervals */
    pen gridpen  = linewidth(0.7) + gray(.7); 
    real dx = 1., dy = 1.; 
    for(real i = ceil(xmin/dx)*dx; i <= floor(xmax/dx)*dx; i += dx)
      draw((i,ymin)--(i,ymax), gridpen);
    for(real i = ceil(ymin/dy)*dy; i <= floor(ymax/dy)*dy; i += dy)
      draw((xmin,i)--(xmax,i), gridpen);

    /* draws axes; NoZero hides '0' label */ 
    Label laxis; laxis.p = fontsize(f); 
    xaxis(xmin, xmax, Ticks(laxis, Step = 1., Size = 2, NoZero),EndArrow(6), above = true); 
    yaxis(ymin, ymax, Ticks(laxis, Step = 1., Size = 2, NoZero),EndArrow(6), above = true); 
}

label(graphic("black","width=7cm"),(0,0),NE); 
layer();

int m=3,n=2; 

ddrawgrid(xmax=m,  xmin=0, ymax=n, ymin=0);
```

[image]

Your `size(7cm,0);` command is saying that the entire output should be 7cm wide.  So when you draw the "black" label with a width of 1cm, it will be about 1/7 of the width of the grid.

You might want to investigate using the `unitsize();` command instead.  This command acts as a scale factor, such that a `unitsize(3cm);` command would result in each of your grid lines being 3cm apart.  Since labels are not scaled by the 'unitsize' command, you will have to define `"width=3cm"` for the "black" label to make it fill one of your grid squares.

```
unitsize(3cm);
settings.tex="pdflatex";

label(graphic("black","width=3cm"),(.5,.5)); 
layer();

label(graphic("black","width=1.5cm"),(1.5,1.5)); 
layer();

draw(unitsquare, red);
draw(shift(1,0)*unitsquare, red);
draw(shift(0,1)*unitsquare, red);
draw(shift(1,1)*unitsquare, red);
```

[image]

### Good luck and stick with Asymptote, it is indeed a very useful language!

Comment: P.S. - One advantage of using the `unitsize` command (instead of `size`) is that your output PDF will automatically be to scale.  That's handy when you're including the PDF in another document where you want 1cm to actually print at 1cm.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight. I tried unitsize, but I could not synthesize something consistent. Then I tried to ignore it because I want to create a routine to perform the function of loading an image with the base side residing on the unit segment that does not depend on scaling.